# Передача файла с помощью Winsock(c++)

Tags: c++, winsock

Не могу передать файл с использованием сокета. Вернее файл передаётся, но постоянно разного размера. Вот фрагмент кода для передачи:

```
FILE *inFile = fopen(this->FullDir, "r+b");
    //FILE *outFile = fopen(this->DeskDir, "w+b");
    if (inFile != 0)
    {
        char* buffer[16384]; //выделяем блок 16Кб
        while (!feof(inFile)) //пока не конец файла
        {
            fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile); //копируем блок
            send(s, (char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);//передаём блок
        }
    }
```

И для приёма сответственно:

```
 do
 {
    msg_len = recv(new_client_socket, (char*)&buffer, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 0);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), output);
  } while (msg_len > 0);
```

Размер файла - 2,50Мб, приходит всегда по разному от 1Мб до 2,2Мб.
Где тут ошибка?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите хотя бы на

```
char* buffer[16384];
```

Зачем вам массив **указателей**? Далее, вы пытаетесь читать `sizeof(buffer)` байт, но сколько вы **реально** читаете? Неужели у вас размер файла строго кратен `sizeof(buffer)`?

Я бы для начала действовал примерно так -

```
char buffer[16384]; //выделяем блок 16Кб
int readed;
while((readed = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile)) != 0)
{
    send(s, (char*)buffer, readed, 0);
}
```

а на приеме

```
do
{
    msg_len = recv(new_client_socket, (char*)buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, msg_len, output);
} while (msg_len > 0);
```

Ну, и добавил бы код обработки ошибок отправления-получения.

Answer (score 0):

Функция send может отправить меньше данных чем было запрошено. Реальное кол-во отправленных байтов можно определить по возвращаемому значению (также может вернуть отрицательное число в случае ошибок).

Также здесь:

> char* buffer[16384]; //выделяем блок 16Кб

размер массива скорей всего будет 65536 байтов (для 32-х битных систем), т.к. объявляется массив указателей на char (вероятно подразумевалось char buffer[16384]).

А здесь, в цикле приема файла:

> fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), output);

в файл будет записан полный размер буфера, независимо от того, сколько пришло байтов.